# How do I insert categories in products in wordpress by code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to insert (not replace) categories that already exists in my website wordpress.
I tried this way:

```
global $wpdb;
$products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` where post_type='product'");

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $array = [];
    array_push($array, 1021);
    array_push($array, 1042);
    array_push($array, 1040);
    wp_set_post_categories(38691, $array, true);
}
```

But unfortunately my code is not working. The numbers 1021, 1042, 1040 is the category ID and 38691 is the product ID. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `wp_set_post_terms()` to insert categories.

```
global $wpdb;
$products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` where post_type='product'");

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_id = $product->ID;
    $categories = array(1021, 1042, 1040);

    wp_set_post_terms($product_id, $categories, 'product_cat', true);
}
```

The `true` tells WordPress to append new categories instead of replacing them

Comment: So, if I want to remove a category from the post, can I use wp_remove_object_terms( $product->ID, $categories, 'product_cat');?

Comment: @RodrigoFranco yes this should work

Comment: I tried, but did not work. Can you help me?